# Does iTunes put my iTunes account information in track files when I import CD albums?

Tags: itunes, music, import, drm, m4a

Does iTunes put my iTunes account information in track files when I import CD albums? I never shared any music because I prefer to buy original CDs but if someone stoles some files of mine can my account be traced back? I imported my CD collection last year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ripped/imported audio tracks do **not** get any account information embedded.

This does not apply to tracks matched via iTunes Match and *replaced* by the AAC version from the store. These tracks **do** contain your Apple ID